# Exception !! message: This app is not Authorised to use firebase authentication

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-play-services, one-time-password

Exception !! message: This app is not Authorized to use firebase authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console.[App validation Failed].  I have added SHA - 1 and SHA - 256 key from play console to firebase project settings, still its not working. When OTP is requested, the above exception pops up. Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make sure that you have enabled PHONE AUTHENTICATION . Go to Firebase console -> Authentication -> Sign-in Methods.
2. Test app on real device not on emulator.
3. Double check SHA1 and SHA-256 .
4. After adding keys again, download updated google-services.json and add in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

I followed following steps.

1. Updated the Firebase auth package in pubspec.yaml
2. Added SHA1 and SHA256 keys in the firebase console in the project setting for both debug and release keystore
3. Linked firebase in the play console from the setting>developer account>linked account> firebase account

Give it a try.